# Free .NET Diagramming Control (like Nevron Diagrams)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, open-source, diagramming

Can anyone suggest a free (or very very cheap) alternative to Nevron Diagrams? I was playing with Open Diagram which is open source but it's very poorly documented and their forum is dead.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [NShape](http://code.google.com/p/nshape/). Haven't worked with it yet but seems nice...

Comment: I just looked at it.  At first I was disappointed to see that it's distributed under GPL, which is a no-go for us.  I decided to download it anyway.  I thought it'd be half-baked as I didn't see much hope for a GPL component on the (commercial-oriented) .NET platform.  I was quite surprised to find that it seemed to be a really high-quality product.  Then I went hunting around an found the main website.  There's a [buy link](http://shareit1.element5.com/programs.html?productid=300365512&language=English) there and it turns out a commercial license for one developer costs about $2,500.

Answer (score 1):

This link may point you in the right path:

[Which ASP.NET Diagramming Library/Control do you Recommend?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/369105/114029)

Take a look at this page for more relevant info:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=C%23+diagramming+library